# docker-ce worked on CentOS 7 VPS but no longer works

Tags: docker, centos7, vps

In middle of September I've rented CentOS 7 VPS, installed `docker-ce` from stable repo there, according to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/) and all was fine.

Today I've realized that docker daemon doesn't working. I've failed to start it with

```
# systemctl start docker
```

and all what I've found with

```
journalctl -xe`
```

was

```
ноя 15 18:19:06 *hostname* systemd[1]: containerd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
```

I've tried to reinstall `docker-ce`, but still cannot start it:

```
ноя 15 18:19:06 *hostname* sudo[24909]: myuser : TTY=pts/5 ; PWD=/home/myuser ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start docker
ноя 15 18:19:06 *hostname* systemd[1]: Starting containerd container runtime...
-- Subject: Начинается запуск юнита containerd.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: <link>
-- 
-- Начат процесс запуска юнита containerd.service.
ноя 15 18:19:06 *hostname* systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Начинается запуск юнита docker.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: <link>
-- 
-- Начат процесс запуска юнита docker.service.
ноя 15 18:19:06 *hostname* systemd[1]: containerd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
ноя 15 18:19:06 *hostname* systemd[1]: Failed to start containerd container runtime.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита containerd.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: <link>
-- 
-- Произошел сбой юнита containerd.service.
-- 
-- Результат: failed.
ноя 15 18:19:06 *hostname* systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита docker.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: <link>
-- 
-- Произошел сбой юнита docker.service.
-- 
-- Результат: dependency.
ноя 15 18:19:06 *hostname* systemd[1]: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
ноя 15 18:19:06 *hostname* systemd[1]: Unit containerd.service entered failed state.
```

What should I do to figure out problem more specific and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably face this issue https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/475

Remove modprobe overlay from containerd unit, which is a dependency for docker unit

One possible solution is to use systemd override features as described in the provided url

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/containerd.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStartPre=
```